# Laravel 5.3 - Show Red Dot (\u0) on json result

Tags: laravel-5.3

I Using Laravel 5.3 and `npm install` & `gulp`,
After that i install `laravel/passport` & `doctrine/dbal` & `sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk` & `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`

Problem:
When i navigate to every page, i check with google source, it will show a lot of "\u0" at top of page
[image: Red Dot at Source, it will error when i get json result]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, 
It is because my routers/web.php file format wrong, i convert this file Encoding to UTF8 , now it solved my problem.

Thanks